# Will accidentally pushing the rewind button of FM2 ruin the whole exposures?

Tags: nikon, film-cameras

I accidentally pressed the rewind button (at the bottom of the camera) of Nikon FM2.

I was at my 15th exposure.

In such situation, what should I do?

Will it destroy my whole exposures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rewind button on manual cameras serves to release the take up spool so that you can use the rewind lever to get the film back into that can. Pushing the button alone doesn’t do anything. Releasing it puts things back how they were.

Side note, on cameras that don’t have multiple exposure support out of the box, you can hold the button down while cranking the film advance lever...this causing the film not to move (because of the release button being held) but the shutter still cocked (allowing you to take a second exposure on the same frame).

Comment: @Hueaco thanks. On multiple exposures point, since FM2 already provided its own dedicated m.e. lever at the top right, we don't want usually use rewind button right?

Comment: @neversaint correct. Use the multi exposure lever on your camera. I mention this workaround for other cameras (like the near featureless k1000) as evidence to my point: simply pressing it doesn’t do anything negative to the film.

Answer (score -4):

Some cameras rewind including the leader.  In that case, you need a "leader retriever" (don't know the proper name) or a darkroom (and we are talking pitch black dark here, not the kind of red light you can use for work with photographic paper) to fix it.  Of course, you then need to shoot 15 (or better 16) completely black photographs (short exposure while leaving the lens cap on) before continuing and hope that the camera aligns them correctly with the already shot photographs so that automated cutting of negatives does not make a hash of the rest.  Personally, I'd likely not bother for a half-shot film and just let it get developed as-is (you won't get billed for or even get prints from the unexposed negatives, so you are just wasting a bit of film and negative development cost).

Comment: The fm2 is a manual camera. Pushing the button doesn’t do anything automated (like rewinding the film)